# Route, set meta title in controller

Tags: 8, routes

I have a route that takes data from APIs, so I would like to set the title in the controller and not in the getTitle function because it would mean calling 2 or more times the same API

Comment: You can return a title by setting #title in the top-level render array that you return

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, not out of the box at least, but there's no reason to. Just use a static var, it will mean the API is contacted only once per request:

```
function getTitle() {
  static $title = '';

  if (!strlen($title)) {
    $title = $this->getTitleFromAPI();
  }

  return $title;
}
```